# What does "Sync Project with Gradle File " really mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradlew

In `Android Studio` there is a button `Sync Project with Gradle File`， I always use it, and it's useful. It will download dependence packages and maybe something more.

But what does it really mean?

Is there a corresponding command in `gradlew`?

If I develop an app just using gradle, NO IDE, what commnd should I use ?

Comment: You wouldn't really, that button refreshes the IDE resources to match your local resources.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The button does what it says: it updates the Android Studio project model to match the contents of the Gradle build file.

There is no corresponding `gradlew` command because there is nothing to synchronize when you work with the command line directly. The dependencies will be updated automatically when you run other Gradle commands such as `compile`.